# Betti numbers and dominant maps?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, betti-numbers

Assume that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is dominant morphism of algebraic varieties. Is there any consequences or relations between the betti numbers or the Hodge numbers of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: You mean something like Riemann-Hurwitz formula for curves?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean?